# Логирование ручного изменения даты и времени ( Android )

Tags: android, android-broadcastreceiver

Пытаюсь сделать лог ручного изменения даты. Настроил `BroadcastReceiver` на событие `android.intent.action.TIME_SET`. Все как надо - отлавливаю события изменения даты и времени , записываю в лог дату которую поставил. Все OK, но есть проблема, необходимо записывать и дату до изменения. **Есть ли возможность узнать еще и дату до изменения ?**

Логирование должно производиться при включенном "режиме полета".
На ум пришел только сервис который постоянно мониторит текущее время , но это решение кажется не правильным.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть такая штука `SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()` - время с момента загрузки устройства. Регистрируете бут ресивер, вычисляете в нём разницу с `System.currentTimeMillis()` и где-то сохраняете. Когда перехватываете `action.TIME_SET` ещё раз считаете эту разницу и сравниваете с сохранённой. Ну и там уже должно быть понятно куда и на сколько переводилось время.

Comment: Спасибо, все очень просто и хорошо работает.